# .NET 5 WebApi Error Handling NotFound Behaving Strangely

Tags: asp.net, exception, http-status-code-404

I have a WebAPI app which has registered a custom exception handler with:

`app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");`

I then have an `ErrorController` with the following code:

```
[Route("/error")]
public IActionResult Error()
{
   if (...)
     return Problem(detail: "Text", statusCode: 403);
   else
     return NotFound();
}
```

This is obviously simplified.

The problem is that with 403 or any other code I've tried (apart from 404) this works fine.

With 404 (whether passed to `Problem` or using `NotFound` directly) I get a new exception raised caused by the system attempting to copy the original exception to a stream:

> ```
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Error while copying content to a stream.
>     ---- System.IO.IOException ...
> ```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possibly related? https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28799

Comment: The very thing - a thousand thanks.